# Wait for the result of an external webservice inside a task

Tags: python, celery

I need to write a bunch of tasks where every task needs to query an external web service. The web service always replies with a 202 ACCEPTED status and points in the Location header to the URI where the result can be polled. The time it takes for this web service to deliver the result can vary from 2 seconds to a minute. I was wondering whats the best approach to program my celery task. For now I send the request and start a while loop till I successfully poll the result, eg:

```
while True:
    result = poll_webservice()
    if result:
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(5)

[ continue with the rest of the task ]
```

While this certainly works it seems very crude to me and also I block the celery worker till the result is polled. Is there any better approach?

Comment: if your are calling a *real* webservice, the script should only go on when it got an answer - see [Dive into Python SOAP page](http://diveintopython.org/soap_web_services/index.html) for some examples

Comment: @JMax, there is a possibility for something like http://docs.picloud.com/rest.html, so he can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You' re surely killing your resources. Just query your external web service and save the URI to be polled (use a cache or a db).Then you can have a [periodic task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) that collects the results, if ready...

Answer (score 0):

I'd be thinking about a celery task that polls the Location provided by the 202 response. If it is completed, then it processes it, else it re-queues itself (or a copy of itself) for some time later.

For bonus points, if you have lots of these tasks, you could increase the time between polls each time the response is not ready.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `task.retry` ?

```
@task(max_retries=100)
def poll_webservice_task(url):
    result = poll_webservice(url)
    if result:
       return result
    poll_webservice_task.retry(countdown=5)
```

Comment: also have to remember to set an appropriate `max_retries`:  `@task(max_retries=None)` for no limit.

Comment: Thats the way to go. I wasn't aware of the `countdown` and `eta` arguments to apply_async. With these arguments and the use of subtasks I think I can solve the problem nicely. Thanks for the input.